# Asynchronous start/stop state transitions

Tags: c#, algorithm, asynchronous, async-await, state-machine

I have a third-party object with asynchronous start and stop methods. Each start and stop may fail with exception. The object is not re-entrant, i.e. I can only call its start or stop method after the previous start/stop has completed.

I need to have a class that handles those transitions to the correct (=last asked) state, while minimizing the number of transitions, allowing my client to submit any number of start/stop requests from any thread at any time.

Currently, I’ve implemented that functionality as endless loop in the async method, however It’s too complex, the loop is over 4 pages long, on each iteration I need to manually switch between 8 states (with the following 3 bits: need to be started/stopped, did tried to start/stop, did failed/succeeded). It smells.

I have a feeling I might be missing something obvious here.
And also that my code looks somewhat similar to what compiler does when compiling an async function.
Is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: Can you show/share the code? Maybe it's more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @RonKlein Thanks for the suggestion. I'll ask my client whether they're OK with that, if yes, will try that codereview.

Comment: @RonKlein The client said they're OK sharing that particular class. Here's the code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114764/46194

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a mutex around the calls. You need to block any other code from calling these methods until the methods return (or signal that they are done).

I would simply wrap the object and add a mutex for the calls. That way you can guarantee that if you don't make two calls at the same time.

You don't need to block on the mutex. You can use something like a producer/consumer queue or a threadpool to synchornize the access.

If you are in a single threaded environment you can also do it with a simple queue (and skip all the multi-threaded objects).

Comment: I’m using monitor to guard my state.
The environment is heavily multithreaded, my code runs on CLR pool threads and also on Media Foundation worker threads.
If I’ll use a queue, and the client will quickly submit 3 requests start, then stop, then start, I’ll have 3 state transitions started-stopped-started, while in this case I only need a single one, to started.

Comment: As you said in the question, you want the last asked state, modify your request queue to empty it before you issue a state change (and ignore everything except the last one).

Comment: Don’t you think the queue that only holds the last value can be replaced with a single bool variable? Why use queue at all?